# Adding padding to the top of body is not fixing the issue with navbar covering content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Below is my HTML and CSS code for a portfolio site that I am creating. My issue is tht when I added my logo to the navbar (which increased the navbar's width) the content started covering the top of each anchor's content. For example, when I click on the "About" anchor it will go to that seciton but the top of the section is covered by the navbar's increased width. I followed the instructions on Bootstraps documentation as well as others on stackoverflow that said to add paddding or margin to the top of the body element but it does not work. Can someone look at my code and tell me if I am doing something wrong?

What it should look like: https://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/391/index.html#services

What mine looks like: https://bootstrap-parallax.herokuapp.com/#services

HTML:

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-main">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand-centered" href="#">
                <img src="img/logo2.png" alt="" />
              </a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-main">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#information">Resume</a></li>
                <li><a href="#map">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.script-tutorials.com/bootstrap-one-page-template-with-parallax-effect/">Blog</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
          </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
```

CSS:

```
/*this changed a heading text color to white*/
.h1, h1 {
  color: white;
}

/*this changed another heading text color to white*/
.h3, h3 {
  color: white;
}

/*this vertically centered the navbar links after the logo made navbar too wide*/
.navbar-nav li a {
  line-height: 35px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: medium;
}

/*this centers the logo on the navbar*/
@media screen and (min-width:768px){
    .navbar-brand-centered {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        display: block;
        width: 160px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .navbar>.container .navbar-brand-centered, 
    .navbar>.container-fluid .navbar-brand-centered {
        margin-left: -160px;
    }
}

/*this pushed the left navbar links to the right */
.navbar-left {
  padding-left: 75px;
}

/*this pushed the right navbar links to the left*/
.navbar-right {
  padding-right: 75px;
}

/* general styles */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

/* padded section */
.pad-section {
  padding: 50px 0;
}
.pad-section img {
  width: 100%;
}

/* vertical-centered text */
.text-vcenter {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.text-vcenter h1 {
  font-size: 4.5em;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* additional sections */
#home {
  background: url(../img/Slide2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

#about {
}

#services {
  background-color: #306d9f;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#services .glyphicon {
  border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 60px;
  height: 140px;
  line-height: 140px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 140px;
}

#information {
  background: url(../img/Slide.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  display: table;
  height: 800px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
#information .panel {
  opacity: 0.85;
}

#map {
  /*width: 500px;*/
  height: 500px;
}

footer {
  padding: 20px 0;
}
footer .glyphicon {
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 60px;
}
footer .glyphicon:hover {
  color: #306d9f;
}

body {
  padding-top: 65px;
}
```

Comment: Add `<br>` tag before your `about` and `services` section. This will move your content bit down. P.S - This is a quick solution not optimized solution

Comment: Sound kind of hacky, lol. There should be a better way, right?

Comment: Ok Pirate, spill the beans my friend. The line break hack didn't work but the .pad-section styling worked like a charm. How did it do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the navbar width is now increased, we have to increase the padding for the div as well to keep the view intact.

`.pad-section { padding: 100px 0; }`

The original template has particular navbar height for particular div padding. Since you changed the navbar, you have to change the div padding as well

**The `br` trick.** 
 While this is not the best option, but sometime it helps as a dead end backup

Instead of putting `br` before the `about` section. Put it like this.

```
<div id="about" class="pad-section">
          <div class="container">
            <br><br><br>
<div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <img src="img/logo.png" alt="">
```

Comment: Thanks Pirate. I have been researching this for over two hours. You rock!

Comment: Anytime Dean. Now I am wondering why the `br` trick did not work.

Comment: @DeanFriedland Check the grey tick to mark the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Tipically in bootstrap is the container of the page that define the proper padding so is not shadowed by navbar.. and you are looking at the navabar .. take a look at the container below the navbase this could be like this

.wrap > .container

```
.wrap > .container-fluid
{
   padding: 45px 15px 20px;
}
```

the 45px padding is related to the eight fo the navbar so .. adjust for your need